sin() returns a slightly different results for the different platforms
I've noticed during CI that this code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    const double d = 3.81219767052986080458;
    fprintf(stderr, "%.20f\n", sin(d));
    return 0;
}


compilled with gcc test.c -lm -o test
returns a slightly different results for my 2 test platforms.
It's -0.62146009873891927544
witn gcc version 13.2.0 libc 2.39-0ubuntu8.3 Kubuntu 24.04
and  -0.62146009873891938646
with gcc version 12.2.0 libc 2.36-9+deb12u7+ci202405171200+astra5+b1 Astra Linux 1.8
I wonder what affects it? libm? gcc? may be CPU?
This slight difference may be accumulated during integration in a tight loops.
Is there a simple way to get rid of it without performance penalties? A gcc compiler param, for example?

Double-precision floating point has only 15 decimal digits of precision.

double has 53 bits of mantissa, which corresponds to about 15 significant decimal digits. Everything past that is meaningless. If the numerical algorithm you use is so unstable that a difference of 1 ULP makes it diverge, you probably need to find a better algorithm.

You can read this answer. double can show more than 15 decimal digits due to the binary encoding but the precision only goes up to 15 digits; anything beyond cannot be relied upon. Since your input d has more than 15 digits, there is not guarantee sin receives the exact same input on both platforms + the results' first 15  digits are the same, which is basically all you can meaningfully compare.

@IgorTandetnik: These differences are with 53 bits. And OP did not say their algorithm is unstable with this difference. There are other reasons to desire reproducible results.

Re "Is there a simple way to get rid of it without performance penalties?" Generally speaking, across all potential platforms: no.

@EricPostpischil That's how I interpreted "slight difference may be accumulated". Small errors accumulating and growing larger is the essence of numerical instability.

This question is similar to: Different values for sin on different CPUs. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Have you looked at the bit patterns in d to ensure that the different compilers are generating the same value for d?

@truf,  Please report  printf("%d\n", FLT_EVAL_METHOD); for each platform to gain more insight into the issue.

@truf "Is there a simple way to get rid of it ...?" Do you want the code now to get the same older less accurate result?

@chux both prints 0. But I've been forced to rename my test.c to test.cpp to try it and then I noticed that the problem isn't reproducible anymore. Both prints -0.62146009873891927544. I guess gcc runs g++ compiler for .cpp file instead of c99-gcc or whatever it uses for .c. Alsoldd test shows no libm lib linked in c++ version of executable. Seems c++ uses own implementation of sin(). In fact my original project code is cpp, but I might use some .c sources in dependencies and link libm for them. Should doublecheck that.

Why do sin(45) and cos(45) give different results?, Floating point accuracy with different languages

Such investigations, shown with hexadecimal of %a can shed light:
int main() {
    double x;
    x = 3.81219767052986080458;
    printf("x:        % -25a % .21g\n", x, x);
    double y = sin(x);
    printf("sin(x):   % -25a % .21g\n", y, y);
    long double yl = sinl(x);
    printf("sinl(x):  % -25La % .21Lg\n", yl, yl);
    y = -0.62146009873891927544;
    printf("13.2.0 :  % -25a % .21g\n", y, y);
    y = -0.62146009873891938646;
    printf("12.2.0:   % -25a % .21g\n", y, y);
    return 0;
}

Output:
x:         0x1.e7f617e06814dp+1      3.81219767052986080458
sin(x):   -0x1.3e30049fb486ap-1     -0.621460098738919386463
sinl(x):  -0x1.3e30049fb48697f8p-1  -0.621460098738919330735
13.2.0 :  -0x1.3e30049fb4869p-1     -0.621460098738919275441
12.2.0:   -0x1.3e30049fb486ap-1     -0.621460098738919386463

From this we can see

The code x = 3.81219767052986080458; results in an double that is very close.  Code values beyond 15 significant decimals places are suspect.  This x is quite close - good to 21 places.

With sin() of the 2 systems, including my own, the answers are within 1 unit in the last place (ULP) of each other.
Using long double math, we get a sinl() of -0x1.3e30049fb4869_7f8p-1.  Note that 7f8 is very nearly half way between the lower precision sin() results of the 2 systems report by OP.  -0x1.3e30049fb4869p-1 is about 4 parts in 100 closer and so the better answer.

I wonder what affects it? libm? gcc? may be CPU?

Many things may affect this including the run-time math (Report value of FLT_EVAL_METHOFD), optimization settings, library used and even the CPU.

Is there a simple way to get rid of it without performance penalties? A gcc compiler param, for example

No.
--
[More]
Although only a few lines long there are 3 places where inexactness may arrive.

double d = 3.81219767052986080458;  The 21-digit decimal constant is converted to a double.  Although the conversion from decimal FP constant to double is not exact, it is close enough here and not a noticeable affect on the final result.

x before:  0x1.e7f617e06814_cp+1      3.81219767052986_036049...
x:         0x1.e7f617e06814_dp+1      3.81219767052986_0804577992894337512552738189697265625
code:                                 3.81219767052986_080458
x after:   0x1.e7f617e06814_ep+1      3.81219767052986_124867...


sin(d) Sine(x) is a transcendental function.  Even when x is exact, the result is nearly always not a rational number (and so not representable exactly as a double).  A good double sin(double) will return a result within about 1 ULP of the correct answer.  Very good double sin(double) will return a result within nearly 0.5 ULP.  For common double, we can see the 2 answers OP found are both nearly 0.5 ULP away from a more precise answer: one above, one below.
sin(x) 13.2.0 is about 0.46 ULP below the better answer while
sin(x) 12.2.0 is about 0.54 ULP above the better answer.

// x from above.
sin(x) 13.2.0 :  -0x1.3e30049fb4869000p-1  -0.621460098738919_275441...
sinl(x):         -0x1.3e30049fb48697f8p-1  -0.621460098738919_330735...
sin(x) 12.2.0:   -0x1.3e30049fb486a000p-1  -0.621460098738919_386463...

I suspect this is due to a better library function in 13.2.0.  Yet even if this one example was a tad worse, the newer library may be better on the average.

fprintf(stderr, "%.20f\n", sin(d)); the conversion of -0x1.3e30049fb4869000p-1 and -0x1.3e30049fb486a000p-1 both print a rounded result.  Yet since enough precision is requested and the conversion was done well, the rounded ouptut is not in error more than expected.  Still I find using the "%a" output more informative.



This slight difference may be accumulated during integration in a tight loops.

The slight difference OP found though is the 1-bit difference in implementations and not the math difference in between sin(x) and the math function sine(x).
An implementation difference in sin(x) can highlight consistency issues - which OP found. Yet it is that math difference OP should be concerned - and not addressed.  That takes a larger analysis and chunk of code to assess.
If the sin() implementation difference generates real result problems (other than exact consistency) which I doubt (would need to see the larger app), then OP's code likely needs higher precision types.
I strongly suspect either result is close enough for OP's needs.  @Igor Tandetnik

it appears to depend on exactly how the range reduction is done. I can get either value in Excel by directly computing sin(x) or computing sin(pi()-x) using the standard double representation of pi. Most system math libraries do range reduction better than that. As you say the true value is rather close to being midway in between.

@MartinBrown Next time use π rather than pi() .  It is possibly a reduction issue, yet I also suspect a computation difference in the reduced x.  IAC, it is only one data point on a nearly half-way case (+/- 0.04 ULP) case.


I wonder what affects it? libm?

Differences in sin for identical inputs are generally caused by different implementations of sin in the standard C library. The implementation of sin may be in a “math library” called libm, or it may be in other files, depending on the platform.
(Another possibility is that the input numeral, 3.81219767052986080458, was parsed differently in the different compiler versions, but that is less likely.)
Ideally, a sin implementation returns the number that equals the mathematical sine of its input operand rounded to the nearest value representable in the floating-point format.1 This would produce the first result you show or, more precisely, −.62146009873891927544065083566238172352313995361328125. However, the C standard does not require this; it allows implementations to produce results that are not correctly rounded.
For some math library functions, humans do not yet know how to compute the entire function with correct rounding in an execution time with a known bound. We can approximate the functions to any desired precision using extended-precision arithmetic, and we can write iterative algorithms that compute more and more precision until the result is known so accurately that we know which way it should be rounded. However, some results of some functions may be so close to the point where rounded changes (halfway between representable values) that a great deal of precision is needed. We do not yet know how much precision is needed for all functions. So we can write an iterative algorithm that works given enough time, but, for some functions, we do not know how much time is required to cover all cases.
Many users would not tolerate math library routines that might, in some cases, run for long periods of time. They want routines that run in short fixed or limited times. Again, it is currently impossible for humans to implement for all math library functions because we do not know how much precision is needed for the worst cases for all of the math library functions.
This is not the case for sine for the IEEE-754 binary32 and binary64 formats (commonly used for float and double). All the worst cases for it have been completely mapped. So a correctly rounded sine can be implemented and it can be done with reasonable speed, although some people prefer faster implementations that are not correctly rounded.
The CORE-MATH project is working on further development of correctly rounded implementations.
Even if somebody has chosen not to implemented a correctly rounded sin, 3.81219767052986080458 is slightly surprising to find a discrepancy in, because it is so small. With periodic functions, the usual design is to reduce arguments outside a base interval to the base interval, then evaluate a polynomial that approximates the function in the base interval. For sine, an implementation usually uses at least a little extra precision for that reduction to the base interval and for the polynomial evaluation, and a little extra precision should suffice for that case. I do note that the sine of the double nearest 3.81219767052986080458 is just about 0.2% away from the midpoint between the two nearest representable values. So eight or nine extra bits ought to suffice. But maybe one of your sine implementations did not do that.

Is there a simple way to get rid of it without performance penalties?

If the problem is in the sin implementation, you would have to use a different math library. Its performance may differ.
Footnote
1 For functions in general, the rounding would break ties in favor of the nearest representable value with an even low digit (bit for base-two floating-point) in its significand. This is not relevant for sine since its only representable operand with a rational sine is zero, so none of the operands involve ties.
